# Symbol OPOS Implementation OPOS_E_NOHARDWARE error

Tags: opos

I have a Symbol/Motorola LS4278 barcode scanner.  I've downloaded the Symbol OPOS Driver software from Symbol's support website.  I'm trying to Claim the device using the VBDemo.exe app that comes with the Symbol OPOS Driver software.  However I am getting the error code OPOS_E_NOHARDWARE.  This means that the device is "not connected or is powered off".  Yet, the device is indeed connected and working fine.  If I scan something with it into Notepad.exe, then the scanned data appears in notepad.  Please advise urgently what I am missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "If I scan something with it into Notepad.exe, then the scanned data appears in notepad."

This tells me that your scanner is programmed for "Keyboard Emulation" mode, sometimes called HID mode.  In the user manual, there will be a programming barcode that you can scan to put it into the proper mode.  Typically for Symbol scanners, it is called "IBM USB mode".  Once you scan this programming barcode, you should be able to use the scanner with OPOS.